# JAVA API to get the typographically correct quotation marks for a specific Locale

Tags: java, locale

Is there an API in Java to obtain the typographically correct quotation marks (opening + closing) for a specific Locale?

See for example this table:

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen#Andere_Sprachen

(It's in German, but one look at the page and you'll know what I mean.)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is actually an interesting question.

Comment: How I solved this a very long time ago was to maintain a Database of quotes for different languages and depending on what language was used first, load these into memory and show seamlessly to the user

Comment: If Alex Stybaevs answer is working for you then please acceppt it, so I will award the bounty...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can try using ICU4J project, e.g. class [LocaleData](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/LocaleData.html)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like this does not: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1286548?tstart=90

But why anyway? If you're doing internationalization you have to translate the words and sentences anyway. So why you want to split the quotation marks from the text?

Or do you have something special in mind?

Comment: Simple use-case: I am developing a word processor like software. The software may run in one language, but the document may be written in a different language. The software shall automatically replace quotation marks without the user even being aware of it. The style of quotation marks may be configurable in a dedicated setting, but it shouldn't have to be, for example it should be derived from other settings first.