# Adding Quotes in Java

Tags: java, android, localization, quotation-marks

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136922/adding-quotes-in-swifthttp://) earlier for Swift, and I'm now facing the same problem in Android/Java.

Is there a way in Java for adding **quotation marks** to a String? The quotation marks should localize properly (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark) based on the user's language settings. The text is stored without quotes in a database. I'd like to show the string in a `TextView`after adding the quotes.

For instance:

```
String quote = "To be or not to be..."
// one or more lines of code that add localized quotation marks
// to the beginning and the end of the string
mMyTextView.setText(stringWithQuotes);
```

For a French user: *«To be or not to be...»*

For a German user: *„To be or not to be...“*

For an English (US) user: *“To be or not to be...*”

Comment: @Reimeus That doesn't set the various types of quotes that the OP is discussing.  Just the English quotes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17433667/java-api-to-get-the-typographically-correct-quotation-marks-for-a-specific-local is the Java answer. However, `LocaleData` does not appear to be in the subset of ICU4J integrated into Android 7.0, and I don't know if ICU4J itself can work on Android.

Comment: @CommonsWare Interesting, thanks. I'll check if I can use it.

Comment: Quickly scanned some info about ICU4J. Does not look so straightforward to use this on Android if at all possible. Might be easier to just handle it with a few `if` statements, especially if the number of supported locales is rather small. Thanks anyway for the pointer.

Comment: @SusannahPotts yes. The comment you replied to was removed before I could see it but I imagine it was just escaping "engineering quotes". It should perhaps be mentioned here that even in English language they are typographically incorrect. I corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried this, but you may be able to use [Locale.getDefault](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html). You could create an enum for each country with different quotations and supply that in the enum. Then it would just be a matter of finding the locale that matches an enum and substituting in the specified locale's quotation mark character.

Comment: Accepted this one because it recognizes that there seems to be no built-in support for this, so it has to be done "manually". It's a bit fuzzy with respect to the actual implementation, and there are many ways to do it. I posted another answer with a simple solution that I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873545/how-to-internationalize-quotation-marks-in-a-jsp) to create the text in HTML which has the necessary mechanisms for handling the quotation marks across locales.

Then you can use [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116162/how-to-display-html-in-textview) to convert the HTML for display in the TextView.

Comment: Thanks - nice trick. I did a quick test adding `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<q>text</q>"));`to my code but the quotes don't show. Googled it, and it seems that the `<q>` tag is not supported by `TextView`.

Comment: On the other hand, this works: `setText(Html.fromHtml("&laquo;text&raquo;"))`. But it also requires some kind of lookup table to match locale and symbols. Can be achieved without HTML by `setText("\u00abtext\u00bb")`.

Comment: Ah that's a bummer about unsupported q tag. I didn't know that. I wonder if the same CSS could be used with another HTML tag it does support though? Maybe not . . . Android may not actually support that either.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following solution:

In order to keep the different types of quotes in sync with the locales supported by my app I create translatable string resources for start and end marks, e.g.

```
<string name="left_quote">\u00ab</string>
<string name="right_quote">\u00bb</string>
```

for French quotes and then add them to my string in code. Pretty simple and easy to maintain.